# QtWebkit: console application

Tags: qt, console-application, qtwebkit

I am new to Qt.

I am building a console application and I need to process lot of real world html pages. QtWebkit comes as an easy choice because of clearly cut APIs and easy availability.

I checked out the docs and they say that I can load pages by using QWebView::load(). But I am building a console application and I cannot use a widget. I get the error as:
?

```
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

So how can I process the html pages using QtWebkit in console application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QtWebkit can be used in a widget-less environment, but can't be executed with QCoreApplication.

The solution is to use a fake X server to execute the program.

Install Xvfb and then:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" ./framecapture google.cat google.png
```

PD: Using framecapture Webkit example from docs: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/webkit-framecapture.html

Answer (score 6):

[`QWebPage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html) can be used in a widget-less environment.

To load a page, do something like this

```
QWebPage page;
QUrl url = ...;
page.mainFrame()->load(url);
```

To get access to the DOM tree, you can use [`QWebFrame::documentElement()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#documentElement). See the [API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html) for how to use this.

Comment: @Job I tried it and it doesn't work. Gives me the same error that GUI is not present.

Comment: @Xolve: Hmm that's very strange... It should work according to the [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwebpage.html#details). I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use the [QtXml](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtxml.html) module directly instead of getting the DOM tree through QtWebKit.

Comment: @Job Actual webpages are better parsed by actual browser.