# QTWebkit "headless" mode

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I'm trying to parse some HTML with QT / C++. However, I don't want to show any rendered HTML page. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt > 4.6, you can use the `QWebElement` as described in this StackOverflow answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Qt. What I meant is "widget-less", but that answer is valid to me. I've also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528076/qtwebkit-console-application